# Error on send email endpoint. Precondition check failed

Tags: gmail-api

I have got an application up and running, and sending emails using the API with no problem at all. But for specific customers, I am getting the following error and I cannot manage to reproduce it. Could you give me further details about the problem? It works for most of my customers

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

I am using the Java Client library from Google, and this is how my code looks I followed the [Google guides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending):

```
MimeMessage content = emailService.createEmail(sendEmailRequest);
Message message = createMessageWithEmail(content);
gmail.users().messages().send(ME, message).execute();
```

The path that the client is hitting is this one `{userId}/messages/send` and these are the scopes the application asks:

```
openid email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: What endpoint are you using? Please include all your code and relevant information about the setup